# Will tomcat return session in case of multiple cookies exist with name JSessionIDs

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Consider a situation where tomcat server receives multiple cookies with name JSessionID out of which one JSessionID is valid, so tomcat will still return a session or not? If tomcat reads only first JSessionID and maps with stored sessions then it may not find valid sesison and may store null. But if tomcat reads all cookies with name JSessionID and checks for existence of session against each JSessionID then it will return valid session. Sometimes we have observed that browser sends two cookies with same name one which is recently authentication session and one some old cookie with stale value. Hence the query to know how tomcat behaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code in tomcat source, a jsessionid cookie will override a jsessionid in the query (provided the context allow to use cookie for session tracking).

If multiple jsessionid cookies are present the first one representing a valid session (for the considered context) will be taken.

see [Tomcat 7.0.x CoyoteAdapter class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java?view=markup) :

```
/**
 * Parse session id in URL.
 */
protected void parseSessionCookiesId(org.apache.coyote.Request req, Request request) {

    // If session tracking via cookies has been disabled for the current
    // context, don't go looking for a session ID in a cookie as a cookie
    // from a parent context with a session ID may be present which would
    // overwrite the valid session ID encoded in the URL
    Context context = (Context) request.getMappingData().context;
    if (context != null && !context.getServletContext()
            .getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes().contains(
                    SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE)) {
        return;
    }

    // Parse session id from cookies
    Cookies serverCookies = req.getCookies();
    int count = serverCookies.getCookieCount();
    if (count <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    String sessionCookieName = SessionConfig.getSessionCookieName(context);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ServerCookie scookie = serverCookies.getCookie(i);
        if (scookie.getName().equals(sessionCookieName)) {
            // Override anything requested in the URL
            if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()) {
                // Accept only the first session id cookie
                convertMB(scookie.getValue());
                request.setRequestedSessionId
                    (scookie.getValue().toString());
                request.setRequestedSessionCookie(true);
                request.setRequestedSessionURL(false);
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug(" Requested cookie session id is " +
                        request.getRequestedSessionId());
                }
            } else {
                if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                    // Replace the session id until one is valid
                    convertMB(scookie.getValue());
                    request.setRequestedSessionId
                        (scookie.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```